# Graph.js tooltip in center of doughnut chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

I have a doughnut Chart that is 30by30px so the tool tip dont realy have any space to show up
It look somewhat like this http://jsfiddle.net/NXPhL/452/

What id like to do if it possible is to have the tooltip static in the midle of the doughtnut.

I founded in the chart.js code that there was an tooltipPosition var so i was tried to give it a x and y cordinate like this

```
var options =
{
    animation: false,
    tooltipPosition:{x:15,y:15}
};
```

But it doesn't work

Is this possible ?

Comment: Well, in highcharts you can set a static position. But this is not highcharts.

Comment: Hum, This is worth checking out. Thanks for letting me know.